# Restkit did not match pattern when response comes back

Tags: ios, restkit-0.20

I have been seeing quite a few posts of this nature where a trailing '/' (or lack of) causes the pattern matching to fail.

My problem, however, is that there is no pattern to match against.
My error looks like this:

> "No response descriptors match the response loaded." UserInfo=0xcb8a660 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://domain.herokuapp.com/auth/identity/callback, 
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=A 200 response was loaded from the URL 'http://domain.herokuapp.com/auth/identity/callback', 
>   which failed to match all (3) response descriptors:
>       http://domain.herokuapp.com pathPattern=(null) 
>       statusCodes=200-299> 
>       failed to match: response path '/auth/identity/callback' did not match the path pattern '(null)'.

"did not match the path pattern '(null)'" is what I assume is the problem.

Setting up the objectmanager and HttpClient:

```
+ (void) fireUpRestkit
{
    RKLogConfigureByName("RestKit/Network", RKLogLevelTrace);

    //base URL @"http://domain.herokuapp.com"
    NSURL *baseURL = [[SCURLManager sharedInstance] baseURL];
    AFHTTPClient * client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:baseURL];

    [client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:RKMIMETypeJSON];

    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [[RKObjectManager alloc] initWithHTTPClient:client];
    NSAssert(objectManager, @"objectManager did not instantiate correctly");
}
```

My request looks like this:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:user
                                           path:/auth/identity/callback"
                                     parameters:nil
                                        success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
```

My descriptors are setup like this:

```
    RKObjectManager *objectManager = [RKObjectManager sharedManager];

RKObjectMapping *userMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[SCUserEntity class]];
[userMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:[SCUserEntity keyMapping]];

RKRequestDescriptor * requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:userMapping.inverseMapping
                                                                                objectClass:[SCUserEntity class]
                                                                                rootKeyPath:nil
                                                                                     method:RKRequestMethodPOST];

RKResponseDescriptor * responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:userMapping
                                                                                         method:RKRequestMethodGET
                                                                                    pathPattern:nil
                                                                                        keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];

[objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];
```

I can't find the reason for the pattern I give when doing the postRequest does not seem to 
be there when the request returns.
I have stepped through the `buildResponseMappingsDictionary` and subsequent matches~ methods. When the request is made they all return the correct descriptors, but when the request needs mapping it doesn't work.

I get a 200 OK from the server, I see both the request and response bodies and they seem correct.

Hope someone can help me spot the probably obvious missing part:)

Comment: What base URL have you set? When you step through, which part doesn't work?

Comment: I added the setup of the objectmanager and httpclient to the question. Nothing fancy there I think. Everything works up until RestKit tries to map the resulting JSON on to a UserEntity. There it seems to fail to get a responseDescriptor that matches the pattern. Error:"failed to match: response path '/auth/identity/callback' did not match the path pattern '(null)'., NSLocalizedDescription=No response descriptors match the response loaded"

Answer (score 5):

It has nothing to do with the path pattern. It's the method.

You are using:

```
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:user ...
```

but you have a response descriptor:

```
method:RKRequestMethodGET
```

i.e. one for POST and one for GET

Comment: Can you elaborate? My understanding is that I setup a RKRequestDescriptor which is used when I do a Post Request with this object and a RKResponseDescriptor when I expect to get this kind of object back from the backend. I am seriously struggling with the new 0.20 version of Restkit.

Comment: Change `method:RKRequestMethodGET` to `method:RKRequestMethodPOST`.

Comment: This helped me. I didn't even think about it.